Non-linear effects (rc splines) in competing risk regression
I use the {tidycmprsk} package to fit competing risk regression models (death/transplantation as competing risk).
E.g.:
crr(Surv(time, status) ~ albumin + creatinine + bilirubin + INR, 
    data = data) %>% 
  tbl_regression(exp = TRUE) %>%
  add_n(location = "level")

Now, I would like to analyze non-linear effects in this model by restricted cubic splines (e.g. rcs(albumin, 4)). However, this seems not to work w/ crr function. Has anyone an idea how this could work?
